# grep pattern not at the begining or the end of sub-string

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

How can I grep only the `"`, which are **not** at the beginning or the end of a "sub-string"?

Hereby, I define a "sub-string" to be characters, separated by a comma `,`. Hence, I want the `"`, which is between `blub` and `didup` as well as the one, which is between `jo` and `ha`.

The following code `grep`s all `"`:

```sh
echo 'test,"blub"didup","jo"ha"' | grep '"'
```

Comment: Maybe `grep '[^,]"[^,]'`? Or `grep -E '(^|[^,])"($|[^,])'` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The second grep also gets the `"` on the end of the string. (BSD)

Comment: The first `grep` command works on BSD and GNU. I guess this should be posted as an answer @WiktorStribiżew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
grep '[^,]"[^,]'
```

It matches

- `[^,]` - any char other than a comma
- `"` - a double quote
- `[^,]` - any char other than a comma.

See an [online `grep` test](https://ideone.com/TLZzEy):

```sh
echo 'test,"blub"didup","jo"ha"' | grep '[^,]"[^,]'
# => test,"blub"didup","jo"ha"
```

Replacing such quotes is possible with `sed`:

```sh
echo 'test,"blub"didup","jo"ha"' | sed ':a; s/\([^,]\)"\([^,]\)/\1 \2/; ta'
# => test,"blub didup","jo ha"
```

See [an online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/do2caZ).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I grep only the `"`, which are not at the beginning or the end of a "sub-string"

Using `gnu grep` you may do this using look arounds to match any double quote that is not at start or end:

```
grep -oP '(?<!^)"(?!$)' <<< 'test,"blub"didup","jo"ha"'
```

Or using any awk:

```
awk -F '[^"]*' '{for (i=2; i<NF; ++i) print $i}' <<< 'test,"blub"didup","jo"ha"'
```